# Open one tab at a time in accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, accordion

I have a accordion which is working absolutely fine but what I need is to open only one tab at a time, means when one tab is opened then another tab should be closed.

Currently you can see that we can open all the tabs by clicking on tab links.

Code here

```
$("#accordion > li > span").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("div").slideToggle(250);
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

});
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RX5J6/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RX5J6/5/)**</kbd>

```
$("#accordion > li > span").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('span').removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(250);
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').slideToggle(250);
});
```

---

Or like:
<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RX5J6/6/)**</kbd>

```
$("#accordion > li > span").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next('div').slideToggle(250)
    .closest('li').siblings().find('span').removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also close other accordions by adding a `beforeActivate` callback:

```
$( ".myAccordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
   $( ".myAccordion" ).not(this).accordion('option', 'active', false);
}
```