# How do I get my accordion to collpsible false when click another

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I want the accordions to be get hide when clicked another. Right now if clck one accordian its getting expanded and when i click on another both are remaining expanded only. Because i am using the class not id.

```
{% for s in data %}
<div class="accordion">
     <h4>Data {{s.id}}</h4>
   <div>
     <p>
      {{s.description}}
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %} 

<script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $(".accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
});
```

i want one accordion collapsed at a time.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15739168/1849444) help?

Comment: Yah i did this. but all accordions are getting expanded.if click on one remaining not closing automatically.

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RX5J6/6/) is a little changed version for class approach does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop must be inside the accordion div:

```
<div class="accordion">
    {% for s in data %}
        <h4>Data {{s.id}} </h4>
        <div>
           <p>
              {{s.description}}
           </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```