# Simplifying two jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I simplify the below jQuery click event into one? It's actually a dropdown that acts like an accordion. When one tab is clicked, the other one slides up if it's expanded.

```js
$('.areazone .title').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    if($('.amenities .title').next().is(':visible')){
        $('.amenities .title').toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    }
});

$('.amenities .title').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    if($('.areazone .title').next().is(':visible')){
        $('.areazone .title').toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="areazone">
    <div class="title">Area Zone</div>
    <ul>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="robertsonquay" type="checkbox" name="robertsonquay"/>Robertson Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="orchardbelt" type="checkbox" name="orchardbelt">Orchard Belt</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="clarkequay" type="checkbox" name="clarkequay">Clarke Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="cbd" type="checkbox" name="cbd">Central Business District</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="boatquay" type="checkbox" name="boatquay">Boat Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="civicdistrict" type="checkbox" name="civicdistrict">Civic District</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="amenities">
    <div class="title">Amenities</div>
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="shopping" name="shopping">Shopping Malls</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="museum" name="museum">Museums &amp; Galleries</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="work" name="work">Work</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="education" name="education">Education</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an event - on click on .title class - on click hide all, show this (that one that received click) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```js
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    var cl;
    if($(this).hasClass( "amenities" )){
    cl = ".amenities";
    }
    else{
    cl = ".areazone";
    }
    if($(cl + ' .title').next().is(':visible')){
        $(cl + '.title').toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="areazone">
    <div class="title">Area Zone</div>
    <ul>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="robertsonquay" type="checkbox" name="robertsonquay"/>Robertson Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="orchardbelt" type="checkbox" name="orchardbelt">Orchard Belt</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="clarkequay" type="checkbox" name="clarkequay">Clarke Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="cbd" type="checkbox" name="cbd">Central Business District</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="boatquay" type="checkbox" name="boatquay">Boat Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="civicdistrict" type="checkbox" name="civicdistrict">Civic District</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="amenities">
    <div class="title">Amenities</div>
    <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="shopping" name="shopping">Shopping Malls</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="museum" name="museum">Museums &amp; Galleries</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="work" name="work">Work</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="education" name="education">Education</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Marco, yours is the best. Just some minor fix I did.

// I had to traverse to parent to see if it has amenities class.
if($(this).parent().hasClass( "amenities" )){
// if true i saved the variable cl as areazone //opposite

//Missing the space
 $(cl+' .title').toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    }

The rest are good.

Comment: Perfect, i didn't have the entire code so i tried to do my best :P

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single clause version:

```
$('.amenities .title','.areazone .title').click(function(){
  var selector = '.amenities .title'
  if $(this).hasClass('amenities') {selector = '.areazone .title'}
  $(this).toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
    if($(selector).next().is(':visible')){
        $(selector).toggleClass('expand').next().slideToggle('2000','easeInOutQuint');
   }
});
```

Comment: You could shorten setting `selector` to one line using a ternary expression to something like `var selector = ($(this).hasClass('amenities') ? '.areazone' : 'amenities') + ' .title';`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one of the css classes to target generic title divs

```
$('div > div.title').click(function() {
    // your code for both...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.title + ul{

      display:none;
    }  



<div class="areazone">
        <div class="title">Area Zone</div>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="robertsonquay" type="checkbox" name="robertsonquay"/>Robertson Quay</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="orchardbelt" type="checkbox" name="orchardbelt">Orchard Belt</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="clarkequay" type="checkbox" name="clarkequay">Clarke Quay</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="cbd" type="checkbox" name="cbd">Central Business District</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="boatquay" type="checkbox" name="boatquay">Boat Quay</label></li>
            <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="civicdistrict" type="checkbox" name="civicdistrict">Civic District</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="amenities">
        <div class="title">Amenities</div>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="shopping" name="shopping">Shopping Malls</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="museum" name="museum">Museums &amp; Galleries</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="work" name="work">Work</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="education" name="education">Education</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>







$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp()
 });
```

fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/e4xeqy8k/7/

Comment: it works too. However when amenities is expanded, and I clicked again, it will toggle up and expand again. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could design an accordion by grouping the title/content within list elements. This simplifies the logic.

I combined your logic with this answer and turned it into a jQueryplugin for easy reuse.

> [Open one tab at a time in accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739045/open-one-tab-at-a-time-in-accordion)

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.accordion = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({
      delay: 250,
      selector: 'div'
    }, options || {});
    var $this = $(this).find('li').find(opts.selector).click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active').next('div').slideToggle(opts.delay)
        .closest('li').siblings().find(opts.selector).removeClass('active').next('div').slideUp(opts.delay);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.accordion').accordion({
  selector: '.title' // Optional
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.accordion {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.accordion>li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
.accordion>li>.title {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 6px;
  background: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.125em
}
.accordion>li>div {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto
}
.accordion>ul li {
  cursor: auto;
}
.accordion li>.title:hover {
  background: #444;
}
.accordion li>.title.active {
  background: #000;
}
.accordion li div > ul {
 list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="areazone">
    <div class="title">Area Zone</div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="robertsonquay" type="checkbox" name="robertsonquay"/>Robertson Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="orchardbelt" type="checkbox" name="orchardbelt">Orchard Belt</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="clarkequay" type="checkbox" name="clarkequay">Clarke Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="cbd" type="checkbox" name="cbd">Central Business District</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="boatquay" type="checkbox" name="boatquay">Boat Quay</label></li>
        <li><label><input class="area-checkbox" id="civicdistrict" type="checkbox" name="civicdistrict">Civic District</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="amenities">
    <div class="title">Amenities</div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="shopping" name="shopping">Shopping Malls</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="museum" name="museum">Museums &amp; Galleries</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="work" name="work">Work</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="am-checkbox" id="education" name="education">Education</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems hard but I see where you're trying to head. It's a jQuery plugin. Very useful though. Thanks.